# Was Lord Vader on Bespin implying that he would like to overthrow the Emporor

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, luke-skywalker

> Luke, you can destroy the Emperor. He has foreseen this. It is your destiny. Join me, and together we can rule the galaxy as father and son.

There are two ways, at least as I understand it, this could be interpreted.

a) Help me get rid of the Emperor to safe the galaxy
b) Help me get rid of the Emperor to become the rulers of the galaxy

Is there any canon or extended source material to support version a) of the interpretation?

Comment: Oh yes. Absolutely.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not finding that myself.